# Посоветуйте хорошую книгу по Linux

Tags: linux, книги

Доброго времени сутрок, посоветуйте хорошую книгу по Linux на русском языке, меня интересуют вопросы администрирования. Настройка ip таблиц, ну и настройка сети. Всем спасибо.

Comment: **На данный вопрос уже ответили** - Мне так не кажется. TS интересуют вопросы администрирования, особенно - администрирование  сети. На РУССКОМ!  А ему предлагают руководство по разработке ядра Linux на английском:-) Навскидку:

Comment: "Сетевые средства Linux". Родерик В. Смит.

Comment: "UNIX: руководство системного администратора". Эви Немет, Гарт Снайдер, Скотт Сибасс, Трент Р. Хейн

Comment: "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4.Руководство по системному администрированию"

Comment: "ALT Linux Master 2.2 Руководство системного администратора".  А. Боковой, И. Вергейчик, О. Власенко, М. Забалуев,

Comment: "ASPLinux Руководство администратора"

Comment: И не пугайтесь того, что я отсылаю Вас к не очень новым руководствам по разным дистрибутивам. Это почти ничего не меняет - настройка IP таблиц - она и в Африке та же самая!